# How to shrink /home

Tags: linux, rhel, partition, storage

I need to shrink my `/home` partition in order to create a new partition. I came across this guide [How to Reduce LVM Partition Size in RHEL and CentOS](https://www.linuxtechi.com/reduce-size-lvm-partition/), but I have a few additional questions.

1. What is the risk of loosing data or causing issues?
2. This is the only guide that I could find. Is it accurate? Or is there a better way?
3. I assume that I can't be logged in while I do this if I unmount /home? Do I have to boot to a tty, or can I just be logged in?

Currently on RHEL 9.

```
└─$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1       259:0    0  1.9T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  240M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0  1.9T  0 part 
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0   70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0 15.5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm  /home
```

Comment: 1. negligible if you follow a decent guide. 2. Looks OK, 3. log in as root, root doesn't need /home, or boot using a linux "recovery" type system like https://www.system-rescue.org/

Comment: If you're using XFS (as is usual on RHEL) you can't shrink it.

Comment: Although negligible as @JaromandaX says, the risk exists with ANY partition manipulation. You should ALWAYS have backups and in this case even more so. Also as A.B points out check which file system you have and if XPS don't even try.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have enough free space, the risk is low, but you should have backups anyway.
2. The guide you found separates the file system and volume resize operations, which is unnecessary and makes the operation more dangerous. It also forces you to unmount the file system, which isn’t necessary.

   In your case a more appropriate guide would be [the chapter on shrinking a logical volume](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/modifying-the-size-of-a-logical-volume_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#shrinking-logical-volumes_modifying-the-size-of-a-logical-volume) in the RHEL 9 documentation.
3. If your file system supports shrinking, it can usually be done online, without logging out or unmounting the file system.